# embedding docusign signature elements in crystal reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, docusignapi

My reports are created in Crystal Reports 2008 (although we have Visual Studio 2015). We are now looking to add Docusign signing elements into the reports. How would we go about accomplishing this? Or, are we going to have to use absolute positioning of the elements on the PDF files produced from the reports?

Comment: Can you elaborate more, do you wish have signature embedded in the report (obviously logic for visibility), or space to add for new signature in the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions:

### Signature Page

You can create a DocuSign template that includes a "Signature page" with text and signing fields. The signature page references the report (which would also be in the DocuSign envelope).

This type of signature "package" is very common in the world of paper documents. Your DocuSign envelopes will include the report, so it is clear that the signer knew what report was included.

### Add Auto-place field locators to the report

If you can set the color of the text via Crystal reports, then you can include Auto-place fields. Simply add text such as **/signature1/** **/datesigned1/** etc to your Crystal Report with the text colored `white`.

Then create a DocuSign template: use the Auto-place option for the DocuSign fields and reference the field locators. Voila: when the report is imported into DocuSign (either via the webtool or API), the DocuSign signature fields will be added to the report in just the right places.

Pro tip: don't use spaces within the field locator text. The conversion to PDF can mess them up resulting in no match with the field's definition.

Because the text color of the locators is white, they will not be visible.

### Add initials fields in the margin

You can set up a DocuSign template with fields that have fixed placement. Eg, add *initials* fields in the margin of the report.